# Silhouette from PolyData in PyVista

Tags: python, vtk, pyvista

I render a PolyData and by calling `lines = mesh.extract_feature_edges()` I obtain its feature lines. Of this set of lines I want to keep only the subset describing the silhouette of the original mesh. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you actually need the edges as a mesh object, or do you just want to plot it?

Comment: I need to obtain the edges.

Comment: I don't want to leave a full answer because I'm not certain, but I wouldn't bet this is possible (although many of my similar such bets have been proven wrong). For plotting you're probably aware of [silhouettes](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/silhouette.html), but the `vtkPolyDataSilhouette()` this uses under the hood doesn't seem to have this functionality based on a quick glance at its docs. Of course the result will depend on the viewing direction, so if something exists for this it would similarly have to be aware of the camera.

Comment: Finally: a `pv.Sphere()` has a silhouette but no feature edges. So in the general case you will have silhouette edges that are not feature edges and vice versa. This seems to be in contrast with the premise of your question.